# JMeter periodic request

Tags: jmeter

I need to create a test plan where:

- A set of requests are executed in the same order as recorded
- A **periodic request** is executed (each X seconds)

So each thread executes recorded requests sequentially and each X seconds also executes a specific request.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Must it be the same thread? could it be two different thread groups too?

Comment: Same thread. Session info is used.

Comment: Have you found a solution back then?) I kind of face the same problem..

Comment: There wasn't solution based at JMeter for that.